# How to get "email" from google api in php

Tags: php, rest

I am tyring to fetch userinfo using google api in php,I am getting following response,But i am not getting "email"
How can i get "email" in response ?

```
<pre>Array
(
    [envelope] => Array
        (
            [alg] => RS256
            [kid] => 819d1e61429dd3d3caef129c0ac2bae8c6d46fbc
            [typ] => JWT
        )

    [payload] => Array
        (
            [iss] => https://accounts.google.com
            [azp] => 407408718192.apps.googleusercontent.com
            [aud] => 407408718192.apps.googleusercontent.com
            [sub] => 101223221895839764325
            [at_hash] => two8g5uanhhgmGszMmnYOQ
            [name] => Amit Sharma
            [picture] => https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/AATXAJxa6BhKJ4UVi8s30wcJEPB3d6u73Fy_9eL3r1_M=s96-c
            [given_name] => Amit
            [family_name] => Sharma
            [locale] => en
            [iat] => 1630134752
            [exp] => 1630138352
        )

)
```

Here is my current code,Where i am wrong ? How can i get user "email" address ?

```
$tokenId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";        
$google_client = new Google_Client();
            $google_client->setApplicationName("Ashojash");
            $google_client->setClientId('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com'); //Define your ClientID
            $google_client->setClientSecret('xxxxxxxxx'); //Define your Client Secret Key
            $google_client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);
            //$google_client->addScope(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login']);
            $google_client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'));
            $google_client->addScope('email');
            $credentials = $google_client->verifyIdToken($tokenId);
            if ($credentials)
            {
                $data = $credentials->getAttributes();
                echo "<pre>";print_R($data);
            }
```